# How to use Haskell ceiling function

Tags: haskell

```
test_1 :: Int -> Int
test_1 y = 5 * 10 ^ (ceiling ( logBase 10 y  ) )  + 100
```

Here is the error message:

```
parse.hs:23:22: error:
    • No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of ‘ceiling’
    • In the second argument of ‘(^)’, namely
        ‘(ceiling (logBase 10 y))’
      In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely
        ‘10 ^ (ceiling (logBase 10 y))’
      In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely
        ‘5 * 10 ^ (ceiling (logBase 10 y))’

parse.hs:23:32: error:
    • No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘logBase’
    • In the first argument of ‘ceiling’, namely ‘(logBase 10 y)’
      In the second argument of ‘(^)’, namely ‘(ceiling (logBase 10 y))’
      In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely
        ‘10 ^ (ceiling (logBase 10 y))’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

But if I try this function by simply using a real number:

```
test = 5 * 10 ^ (ceiling ( logBase 10 1000 ) )  + 100
```

It works fine.

Comment: That is because here your `y` is *not* interpreted as an `Int` but as a `Floating`.

Comment: In Haskell there are no implicit numeric type conversions, you have to be explicit about them, e.g. by using `fromIntegral` and similar conversion functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But if I try this function by simply using a real number:
>
> ```
> test = 5 * 10 ^ (ceiling ( logBase 10 1000 ) )  + 100
> ```

Here `1000` is *not* interpreted as an `Int`, but as a `Floating` type. This is necessary, since the type of `logBase` has type [**`logBase :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:logBase).

You can convert an `Integral` type like an `Int` to a `Num` type with [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral):

```
test_1 :: Int -> Int
test_1 y = 5 * 10 ^ ceiling (logBase 10 (fromIntegral y)) + 100
```

But perhaps it makes more sense to perform the log10 in integer space instead.